# Write from CSV to yaml file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, yaml

Wondering if anyone can help me with outputting this to a yaml file?

As at the moment it only writes the last array returned to the yaml file.

```
       require 'csv'
       require 'yaml'
          #fp = File.open("vatsim-row.txt")

CSV.foreach("vatsim-data.txt", :col_sep =>':', :row_sep =>:auto, :quote_char => ":") do |row| 

if (row[3] == "PILOT") and (row[13]=="EIDW" or row[13]=="EICK" or row[13]=="EINN" or row[13]=="EIKN" or row[13]=="EIDL" or row[13]=="EICM" or row[13]=="EIKY" or row[13]=="EISG" or row[13]=="EIWF" or row[13]=="EIWT" or row[11]=="EIDW" or row[11]=="EICK" or row[11]=="EINN" or row[11]=="EIKN" or row[11]=="EIDL" or row[11]=="EICM" or row[11]=="EIKY" or row[11]=="EISG" or row[11]=="EIWF" or row[11]=="EIWT")

p row 

p row.count

File.open("pilots.yml", "w") {|f| f.write(row.to_yaml) }

elsif row[3] == "ATC" and (row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EGC" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EID" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EIC" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EIN" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EIK" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EIS" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EIW" or row[0].slice(0, 3) == "EIM")

              p row
              p row.count
            end

      end
```

The sort of output i'm looking for in the yaml file:

```
---
clients: 
 callsign: RYR87LN
    cid:        "123456"
    name:       Joe Blogs EIDW
    type:       PILOT
    lat:        "48.28681"
    long:       "-4.03478"
    altitude:   "30883"
    groundspeed:"438"
    aircraft:   B738
    p_cruise:   "300"
    dep:        LFRS
    p_alt: FL310
    arr: EIDW
    server: EUROPE-C2
    pro_rev: "100"
    rating: "1"
    squawk: "2200"
    facilitytype:
    vis_range: 
    p_flighttyp: "0"
    route: FPL-RYR87LN-IS-B738/M-ZSRWY/S-REG/EI-DAH COM/TCAS RVR/200 OPR/RYRVIRTUAL.COM DOF/110813- A/BLUE/WHITE/YELLOW /V/ TERPO UM616 KORER UN482 DEGEX UN490 BERAD UM142 INSUN UN34 EVRIN N34 BUNED
    atismsg:
    lt_atis:
    logon: "20110813151905"
    heading: "310"
    qnh_ig: "29.79"
    qnh_mb: "1008"
```

If anyone can point me in the direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file for appending. Opening a file with mode `w` truncates it to 0 length, effectively you're overwriting it every iteration of the loop.

Use this:

```
File.open("pilots.yml", "a") {|f| f.write(row.to_yaml) }
```

Better yet, leave the file open for appending through out the program instead of repeatedly opening and closing it. Then you probably *will* want to truncate the file:

```
File.open("pilots.yml", "w") do |f|
  CSV.foreach("vatsim-data.txt", :col_sep =>':', :row_sep =>:auto, :quote_char => ":") do |row| 
    # ...

    f.write(row.to_yaml)

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's perfect did the trick thanks a mill @Meagar.

And to think so easy!